# Azure CosmosDB sql join not returning results when the child contains empty array

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

we have the below json structure. Having nested array of objects. Some arrays may be empty.

```
[
{
    "adjustments": [
        {
            "id": "1_0000001",
            "clientID": 1,
            "adjustmentID": "0000001",
            "chargeID": "0000001",
            "dateOfEntry": "2019-01-29T00:00:00",
            "adjustmentAmount": 200
        }
    ],
    "payments": [
        {
            "id": "1_0000001",
            "clientID": 1,
            "paymentID": "0000001",
            "chargeID": "0000001",
            "dateOfDeposit": "2019-01-28T00:00:00",
            "dateOfEntry": "2019-01-29T00:00:00",
            "paymentAmount": 250,
        },
        {
            "id": "1_0000002",
            "clientID": 1,
            "paymentID": "0000002",
            "chargeID": "0000001",
            "dateOfDeposit": "2019-01-28T00:00:00",
            "dateOfEntry": "2019-01-29T00:00:00",
            "paymentAmount": 50,
        }
    ],
    "id": "1_0000001",
    "clientID": 1,
    "chargeID": "0000001",
    "encounterID": "0000001",
    "patientID": "1234567"
    "dateOfServiceBegin": "2019-01-20T00:00:00",
    "dateOfServiceEnd": "2019-01-20T00:00:00",
    "dateOfEntry": "2019-01-21T00:00:00",
    "location": "Main Campus",
    "chargeTotal": 500

},
{
    "adjustments": [],
    "payments": [],
    "id": "1_0000001",
    "clientID": 1,
    "chargeID": "0000001",
    "encounterID": "0000001",
    "patientID": "1234567"
    "dateOfServiceBegin": "2019-02-20T00:00:00",
    "dateOfServiceEnd": "2019-02-20T00:00:00",
    "dateOfEntry": "2019-02-21T00:00:00",
    "location": "Main Campus",
    "chargeTotal": 500
}
]
```

i am trying to execute the below query

```
SELECT udf.getMonthAndYearPart(c.dateOfEntry) as date, sum(p.paymentAmount) as paymentAmount , sum(c.chargeTotal) as chargeAmount , sum(a.adjustmentAmount) as adjustmentAmount FROM c
JOIN p IN c.payments 
JOIN a IN c.adjustments 
where c.dateOfEntry >= '2019-01-11T18:30:00.000Z' and c.dateOfEntry <= '2020-12-30T18:30:00.000Z' 
GROUP BY udf.getMonthAndYearPart(c.dateOfEntry)
```

I am expecting the below result

```
[
    {
        "date": "January-2019",
        "paymentAmount": 300,
        "chargeAmount": 1000,
        "adjustmentAmount": 400
    },
    {
        "date": "February-2019",
        "chargeAmount": 500,
    }
]
```

But I got only first object

```
[
    {
        "date": "January-2019",
        "paymentAmount": 300,
        "chargeAmount": 1000,
        "adjustmentAmount": 400
    }
]
```

Is there anything i can do without join? I want to calculate the sum of child objects amounts with group by month.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by myself. using sub queries and group by. below one is the query in case anyone need this.

```
Select sum(k.totalPaymentAmount) as totalPaymentAmount,sum(k.totalAdjustmentAmount) as totalAdjustmentAmount,sum(k.totalCharge) as totalCharge,k.date as date From (SELECT 
(SELECT value sum(c.paymentAmount) FROM c IN RevenueAnalytics.payments) as totalPaymentAmount,
(SELECT value sum(c.adjustmentAmount) FROM c IN RevenueAnalytics.adjustments) as totalAdjustmentAmount,
RevenueAnalytics.chargeTotal as totalCharge,
udf.getMonthAndYearPart(RevenueAnalytics.dateOfServiceBegin) as date
FROM RevenueAnalytics) k
Group BY k.date
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you would need to do a LEFT JOIN in your query to include the cases of documents with empty adjustments or payments. LEFT JOIN at the moment is not supported, you can vote [this thread](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/37949650-support-left-join) to include this feature. In the meanwhile you can create a procedure and do two separate queries, one as you are doing using joins, and the other not using joins and filtering (where clause) for entries with array_length 0 for adjustments and payments, and then aggregate all results and result.